# Pagination Laravel 5 Make Limit for Pagination

Tags: php, pagination, laravel-5

My pagination custom is work, but I want make limit on my pagination.

Now my pagination is like this,

<< < 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 > >>

but I want make limit like this,

<< < 1 2 3 4 5 > >>
when page 5 active will be like this,

<< < 3 4 5 6 7 > >>

The point is I want make limit. Because I just thinking how if I have 1000 page, this is so bad.

This is my Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Member;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;


class IncomeController extends Controller
{
    public function show()
    {
        $users = User::paginate(1);
        $users->setPath('income');
        return view('member.income.list')->with([
            'title' => 'Income Data',
            'userPage' => $users,
            ]);
    }
}
```

And my view

```
@extends('app')
@section('content')
        <div class="row">
        <table border="1">
            @foreach($userPage as $users)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$users->name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$users->last_online}}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>


        @include('pagination.default',['paginator'=>$userPage])
        </div>
    <hr>
@stop
```

My Custom Pagination View

```
@if($paginator->lastPage()>1)
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="{{($paginator->currentPage()==1)?'disabled':''}}">
          <a href="{{$paginator->url(1)}}" aria-label="Previous">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="{{($paginator->currentPage()==1)?'disabled':''}}">
          <a href="{{$paginator->url($paginator->currentPage()-1)}}" aria-label="Previous">
            <span class="fa fa-angle-left"></span>
          </a>
        </li>
        @for ($i=1; $i <= $paginator->lastPage(); $i++)
        <li class="{{($paginator->currentPage() == $i)?'active':''}}">
          <a href="{{$paginator->url($i)}}">
            {{$i}}
          </a>
        </li>
        @endfor
        <li class="{{($paginator->currentPage()==$paginator->lastPage())?'disabled':''}}">
          <a href="{{$paginator->url($paginator->currentPage()+1)}}" aria-label="Previous">
            <span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="{{($paginator->currentPage()==$paginator->lastPage())?'disabled':''}}">
          <a href="{{$paginator->url($paginator->currentPage()+1)}}" aria-label="Next">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
          </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
@endif
```

Comment: Do you really want 1 registry per page?